# Javascript date string picking up incorrect month

Tags: javascript, date-formatting

I have a date like this:

> Wed Apr 06 2016 12:21:07 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

I need the month out of this date. My code is:

```
dateText= "Wed Apr 06 2016 12:21:07 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
var x = new Date(dateText);
var y = x.getMonth();
console.log(y)
```

the value of y comes out to be 3. But ideally, it should ve been 4 (since the month is April). The alternative I have thought of is to split the dateText by space i.e.

```
arrDate = dateText.toString.split(" ");)
```

and then extract the month from arrDate array.

***Can anyone tell my why javascript is showing '3' instead of '4' in my first code above?***

Comment: Maybe read the documentation of getMonth? ;-)

Comment: Which is here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Comment: Thanks for the help. I forgot getMonth starts from zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DATE_OBJECT.getMonth()` is zero based. (0 for January and 11 for December).

You need to do `var y = x.getMonth() + 1;`

See documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp

Comment: Or the better documentation here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Answer (score 1):

`getMonth` starts from zero

```
dateText= "Wed Apr 06 2016 12:21:07 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
var x = new Date(dateText);
var y = x.getMonth() + 1;
console.log(y)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because the getDate() function returns a value from 0-11, so if you try to get the 4th month it will return 3.